# How would I post a video to youtube without downloading it

Tags: youtube

I have quite a few videos hosted on a server (as mp4s) that I would like to upload directly to youtube without the hassle of first downloading the videos to my laptop. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage [Youtube's Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video). Write a python script that will run on your server and upload them to youtube with the API.

Comment: It's not my server. I'm supposed to view someone else's mp4 on their server, but it is improperly configured so that I must download each before viewing. Unfortunately due to current network issues (due to coronavirus), this is very impractical as I cannot do any work for the 2 hour download time of a 20 min video. Hence I would like to somehow have youtube pull the video directly from the public mp4 link and upload that privately. Is this possible?

Comment: If you don't have access to the server you can't make it upload something somewhere. You could make youtube download it from your server if the API allows it, you could try giving it an URL instead of a local filepath, run it from your computer and see if it works.